# How to use both callback_data and url in InlineKeyboardButton python telegram

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to count how many users clicked on a button and I used callback_data for it :

```
for n in list2 :
     buttons.append([InlineKeyboardButton(n[0], callback_data=f"click on { n[0] }" , url = "https://t.me/test")])
context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(buttons), text="List of my channals")
```

the button does open the URL but it doesn't make a callback request and when I delete the url parameter callback works as expected ... is there a way to use both parameters at the same time ?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same thing, but apparently **you can't**. The callback_data and url are mutually exclusive arguments.

You can find more info here: https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.inlinekeyboardbutton.html